# Getting an Unexpected T_Function Error and I don

Tags: php, wordpress, function, parse-error

This may be a dumb question. I am getting an unexpected T_ERROR for the following code in my WordPress Functions.php file. This happens often and I review the code several times seeing no problems... So I've decided to ask someone why.

Thank you.

```
<?php
/*
**Remove WordPress 'w'
*/
function annointed_admin_bar_remove() {

    global $wp_admin_bar;

    /* Remove their stuff */
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wp-logo');
}

add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'annointed_admin_bar_remove', 0);

/*
** Remove WordPress Dashboard Widgets
*/

function remove_dashboard_widgets() {

global $wp_meta_boxes;

unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_quick_press']);

unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_right_now']);

unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_plugins']);

unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_recent_drafts']);

unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_primary']);

unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_secondary']);

}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets' );

?>
```

Comment: What is the exact t_* error?

Comment: What is the entire error message?

Comment: welcome to s.o don, please read the help section on how to ask a question